# Apply updated data to line/path?

Tags: d3.js

I have a line graph which is updated based on values chosen from two dropdown lists.  The data is updated as per gist below.  Everything is working perfectly and all data is being returned correctly but when try to apply this updated data to the existing line/path and update the graph - the line/path disappears and I get a parsing error.  Know it is something to do with how I'm applying this new data to the line/path  - can anyone help?

https://gist.github.com/Majella/202df0a4a5a3ad20fb92

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure if you'd like to (a) update the existing line with new data, or (b) keep the existing line and add a second line with the new data.

For (a), you would need to re-join `newdata` to the original line and then redraw it. This can be achieved with a simple redraw function where the function parameter is the dataset. You can see an implementation of this in Mike Bostock's [General Update Pattern](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3808234) post or in an [even simpler example](http://tributary.io/inlet/5127223) I made to demonstrate this.

If (b), you would perform a data-join for the new data as you did for the first dataset, something like:

```
var data2 = svg.selectAll('.newData')
   .data(newdata)
.enter().append('path')
   .attr('class', 'newData)
   .attr( "d", line(newdata));
```

And it would add a second line to the graph.

Comment: Thank you.  I would like update the existing line with the new data which I have attempted to do in my code (see gist) -  I have rejoined new data to the this line but causing a parsing error?

Comment: In your example you have not rejoined the data because doing so involves setting a new value for selection.data([values]). You first join data to `svg.selectAll('dot').data(data)`. This is the type of thing you have to do the second time. When you below say `.attr('d', line(newdata)` it is in fact still drawing from the original dataset because you have not joined the data in the .data([value]) format.

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure I understand what you mean?  I did try this svg.select("path.line").data(newdata).transition().ease("linear").duration(750) .attr( "d", function(d) { return line(d.values); }); but line still disappearing and still getting "problem parsing d" error?